# Import "flask_sqlalchemy" could not be resolved from source: Pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I have tried all of the other solutions before posting here so I hope this does not get removed.
Error comes form this line:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

I am running the latest version of VSCode.
Things I've tried from within my virtual envionment (venv)

```
1. pip install flask_sqlalchemy
2. pip3 install flask_sqlalchemy
3. pip install flask_sqlalchemy --user
```

I also have my python VSCode python interpreter set to the the interpreter within the virtual environment.

I can see the flask_sqalchemy is installed within my **requirements.txt:**

```
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
```

I really don't know what else to try at this point.

Comment: Can you provide the error information? I followed your description and found no problem

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, I messed around a lot reinstalling things so I'm not 100% sure what the perfect solution is but this is what finally worked for me.

View -> Command Pallete -> Python: Select Interpreter -> Select the version that says 'Global'

Then follow the same steps but instead select the version that says 'Recommended'.

I am assuming it somehow reinitialized the version of python I was trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but I was using pipenv which sets up a special environment for the execution with the python modules installed in that environment. When I execute the "pipenv shell" command, the response shows me the environment that is created and has the version of the interpreter that should be used for this environment.

The line I get is:
myuser@Pspec7:~/pydev/flask$ . /home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/flask-E0DF0fBp/bin/activate

When you get to the point where you can select your interpreter: In the interpreter list look for the path that corresponds to your environment.

From the line above, my interpreter was: Python 3.8.10 ('flask-E0DF0fBp')

This was for me. You need to look for your correspoding string.
Without setting the interpreter correctly, it cannot look through the packages you have installed.